# Discord-py Rewrite - Basic aiohttp webserver in a Cog

Tags: python, python-3.x, sockets, discord.py, aiohttp

I am trying to integrate a basic aiohttp webserver in a Cog (using discord-py rewrite). I am using the following code for the cog:

```
from aiohttp import web
import discord
from discord.ext import commands

class Youtube():

    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    async def webserver(self):
        async def handler(request):
            return web.Response(text="Hello, world")

        app = web.Application()
        app.router.add_get('/', handler)
        runner = web.AppRunner(app)
        await runner.setup()
        site = web.TCPSite(runner, '192.168.1.111', 8999)
        await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
        await site.start()

def setup(bot):
    yt = Youtube(bot)
    bot.add_cog(yt)
    bot.loop.create_task(yt.webserver())
```

It works fine upon starting the bot.
But if I reload the cog while the bot is running, I encounter an issue:

> OSError: [Errno 10048] error while attempting to bind on address
>   ('192.168.1.111', 8999): only one usage of each socket address
>   (protocol/network address/port) is normally permitted

I cannot think of an simple/elegant way to release and re bind every time the cog is reloaded.
I would love some suggestions on this. The end goal is to have a cog that supports youtube pubsubhubbub subscriptions.

It might just be that there is a better way to integrate a basic webserver to my bot. I could use a deamon (fork) upon starting the bot for example (I already have a webserver written using HTTPServer with a BaseHTTPRequestHandler that can handle pubsubhubbub youtube subscriptions) but somehow I have my mind set on integrating it in a cog using aiohttp :)

Comment: If you define an `__unload` method (not a coroutine) of the cog, that will be called when the cog is removed.  Your `webserver` method should make a reference to `site` available through `self` that `__unload` can then use to call `site.stop`

Comment: `def __unload(self):
  self.site.stop()` I get: RuntimeWarning: coroutine 'BaseSite.stop' was never awaited which makes sense but I don't know how to fix it :(

Comment: Probably `self.bot.loop.run_until_complete(self.site.stop())`?  Or something similar.

Comment: I went with `asyncio.ensure_future(self.site.stop())` and it seems to be working. Thanks!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```py
    from aiohttp import web
    import asyncio
    import discord 
    from discord.ext import commands
        
        class Youtube():
        
            def __init__(self, bot):
                self.bot = bot
        
            async def webserver(self):
                async def handler(request):
                    return web.Response(text="Hello, world")
        
                app = web.Application()
                app.router.add_get('/', handler)
                runner = web.AppRunner(app)
                await runner.setup()
                self.site = web.TCPSite(runner, '192.168.1.111', 8999)
                await self.bot.wait_until_ready()
                await self.site.start()
    
            def __unload(self):
                asyncio.ensure_future(self.site.stop())
        
        def setup(bot):
            yt = Youtube(bot)
            bot.add_cog(yt)
            bot.loop.create_task(yt.webserver())
```

Thanks [Patrick Haugh](https://stackoverflow.com/users/6779307/patrick-haugh) !!